# Keep reset style sheet in a separate file

Tags: css, wordpress

So we all know CSS resets are great and wise to have. However these reset style sheets can be quite long and I do not want to keep the reset styles in my main style.css file. Rather I would like to have a separate reset style sheet file.

How can this be done with Wordpress using **functions**?

So far I have just included `@import url('layouts/normalize.css');` in my styles.css and this works, but I do not know if this is the best approach.

FYI I am using a _s based theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

**UPDATE**

With right (template) URI:

```
wp_enqueue_style('resetCss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/normalize.css');
```

You can add this code to your `function.php` or any [init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook / action.

Comment: Is it appears in your source? And did you call the `resetCss` function? Try tp apply it without function first.

Comment: Try tp apply it without function first from your `functions.php`. If it will appear in the source, then you do not call your function. Please read the reference.

Comment: cool, maybe the path was wrong. please accept my answer if it worked for you, thanks.